# Example for Carleman Linearization resulting in a linear system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, nonlinear-system, linearization

The Carleman linearization came to my attention due to this [article](https://www.quantamagazine.org/new-quantum-algorithms-finally-crack-nonlinear-equations-20210105/). I tried to understand this method but so far i wasn't succesful i tried to understand page 39 of [this presentation](http://www.cds.caltech.edu/doyle-fest/presentations/pdfs/bamieh.pdf) however the example didn't make sense for me.

#### Could someone demonstrate how to compute a Carleman linearization and demonstrate/argue that the resulting linear ODE behaves similar to the non linear system?

I would prefer a demonstration that

- $\frac{dx}{dt} = f(x,t)$ has a multidimensional $x$
- $f(x,t)$ is non linear in $x$
- It would be nice if the nonlinear system is well understood.  Examples would be the single or double inverse pendulum, Dubins car, SIR model, Lotka-Volterra  but that is not a requirement
- shows what role initial conditions play

If there is some visualization (for example a phase portrait) that shows how a finite approximation of the infinite dimensional linear equation breaks and how it gets better if a larger finite dimensional approximation is used please also add that.

Are there some well understood conditions when a Carleman linearization will be non successful in reproducing the dynamics?